# jQuery to display all data associated with checked radio button

Tags: jquery

I am generating dynamic radio buttons from an array being returned from a service. Each item being returned contains address data. I know how to get the value fro the data, but how can I get all the values from the item that's selected? Here's what I have so far:

```
function showAddresses(item) {
    window.addNo2 = item.streetno;
    window.addStr2 = item.streetname;
    window.addCity2 = item.city;
    window.addSt2 = item.state;
    window.addZip2 = item.zip;
    window.latLong2 = item.latlng;
    $('#multiAdds').show();
    $('#results').append('<p><input type="radio" name="multiAdds" class="radioButton" onclick="getChecked()" value="' + latLong2 + '">' + addNo2 + ' ' + addStr2 + </p>');
}

function getChecked(){
    var latLong2 = $("input[name=multiAdds]:radio:checked").val();
    getJurisdictionMulti(latLong2, addNo2, addStr2, addCity2, addSt2, addZip2);
}
```

I basically need to be able to grab all the associated address data from the selected radio button and create separate variables with them to be able to pass into my getJurisdictionMulti() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML-5 **data-*** Attributes for such cases..
Here is a simple case( Rough Example) , which can **still be optimized..**

Let's call this attribute **data-custom**

```
var custom =  latLong2 + ',' + addNo2 + ',' + addStr2 + ',' + addCity2
             + ',' + addSt2 + ',' + addZip2 ;
$('#results').append('<p><input data-custom="' + custom + '" type="radio" name="multiAdds" class="radioButton" onclick="getChecked()" value="' + latLong2 + '">' + addNo2 + ' ' + addStr2 + </p>');


function getChecked(){
    var values = $("input[name=multiAdds]:radio:checked").data('custom').split(',');
    var latLong2 = values[0] ;
    var addNo2 = values[1] ;
    var addStr2 = values[2] ;
    var addCity2 = values[3] ;
     var addSt2 = values[4] ;
    var addZip2 = values[5] ;
    getJurisdictionMulti(latLong2, addNo2, addStr2, addCity2, addSt2, addZip2);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this won't work in IE8 since it's HTML5. This needs to work in all browsers.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem with IE- 8

Comment: You are correct. This works perfectly... even in IE8. Thank you for your help.